# Android Virtual Device does not show my buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on an Android project and this is my FIRST Android program. Anyway, I've been using my Galaxy Note 10.1 to test my program and it does seems to display nicely; but today when I tried to use Android Virtual Device with different settings, all the buttons from my program does not display. I tried to search around but could not find the solution to this so may be a post might help me get an answer to this question. Thanks!

I don't have enough reputation to post images and more than 2 links; so I will just post a link to my preview image. The AVD output only shows the background image but not the buttons

[image]

Here are my current setting for this AVD:
Device: 10.1" WXGA (Tablet) (1280 x 800: mdpi)
Target: Android 4.1.2 - API Level 16
CPU/ABI: ARM (armeabi-v7a)
Keyboard: (checked) Hardware keyboard present
Skin: HVGA
...
Emulation Options: (checked) Use Host GPU

Also, my current Android project build target is:
android 4.1.2 Api level 16

Comment: I think you have any layouts for any display

Comment: it said too long; which part of the codes do you want to look at?

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62953762/activity_main_xml.png. This is the top part of the main_activity.xml

Comment: This is the 2nd part where I added the buttons. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62953762/activity_main_2.png

Comment: and this is the last part of the main_activity file.https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62953762/activity_main_3.png